# Writing to a database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently finishing an asp.net project for a class and began to notice a major flaw with one of the requisites.  The application should ask five questions and write the answers to a database, afterwards it should display the results of the survey to the user.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
 public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string connStr = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2};" + "database= -table to be accessed-; pooling=false", 
            "-database server-", "-user-", "-password-");
        return connStr;
    } 

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            string sex = gender.Text;
            string likes = interests.Text;
            string edu = education.Text;
            string nation = nationality.Text;
            string userage = age.Text;

            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mycon;

            mycon = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO survey (gender, age, birthplace, occupation, winner) VALUES ('" + sex  + ", " + likes + ", " + edu + ", " + userage + "')", mycon);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mycon.Open();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                mycon.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

I went ahead and replaced the database information with placeholders.

The database is MySql and hosted on an external server.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the code compiles, however the information does not get written to the database.  I'm not certain if this is due to the fact that I'm still testing the code and have not uploaded the web application to the server or the fact that it's just wrong.

As far as displaying the results go, if the above code is correct it would simply be a matter of changing the sql query, correct?

Thanks in advance for the insight.

Comment: Are there error messages?

Comment: Nothing that raises any flags.  It "works" perfectly in the sense that it compiles and loads.  It simply fails to do its job.

Comment: You should be getting an error or exception.  You may have other problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing the command before opening database connection.

`ExecuteNonQuery()` method and all other Execute method require an open database connection.

And another error is:
Number of columns (i.e. 5) and provided values (i.e. 4) are not equal.

And [one more issue in your code is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043332/writing-to-a-database-in-asp-net/15043437#15043437) as stated by [Steve Wellens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479869/steve-wellens).

Change Your Code like below:

```
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO survey (gender, age, birthplace, occupation, winner) VALUES ('" + sex  + ", " + likes + ", " + edu + ", " + userage + "')", mycon);
    mycon.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}    
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}    
finally
{
    mycon.Close();
}
```

---

## Security Notes:

Never add `data` into query using `+` operator. It may cause [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection).

What if a user enters `1); DROP TABLE <table-name> --` in `Age` `TextBox`..??
Anyone can delete any table entirely from database.

Use [MySQL Parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html) to avoid such problems. It may prevent from causing serious damages to your entire database.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the security flaws.  The only thing the professor had mentioned was limiting the permits of the user but somehow I don't think that's quite as effective as MySQL Parameter.

Comment: It is still not writing to the database, would you happen to know if that's related to the fact that the application is still not loaded into the server?  I'm still using Visual Studio to finish it.

Comment: If it is not writing to database then u must b getting n exception. Can u pls tell me the exact error message..?

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string:

```
"database= -table to be accessed-;
```

...you don't put the table.  The table is specified in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

you should open the connect first, then execute the query.

```
    try
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO survey (gender, age, birthplace, occupation, winner) VALUES ('" + sex  + ", " + likes + ", " + edu + ", " + userage + "')", mycon);
                    mycon.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not the only problem, but it is *a* problem:

```
"INSERT INTO survey (gender, age, birthplace, occupation, winner) " + 
"VALUES ('" + sex  + ", " + likes + ", " + edu + ", " + userage + "')",
```

(I've broken it into two strings to make it easier to read.)

You are inserting into five columns.  You are only specifying four data values, and with the exception of gender they don't appear to be in the right order or even be the right data.

Comment: Wow, I had completely overlooked that.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

try checking these things :

1. try opening your connection before executing the SQL
2. check your SQL, and try execute them directly against the database. what i see in your SQL is you are concatenating the values into one string (quotes exist only in beginning and end, but not in between the parameters passed)