# Classic ASP code to receive HTTP POST data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm working on a little project and in this one area I seem to be out of my depth. My Google-fu is not helping me with my specific issue.

I have an ASP web application that I'm modifying and have added an HTML canvas to it. I want to send the canvas data to my Windows web server and handle it there (just saving to a file would do for now).

I have Javascript in the browser that I think is right:

```js
// PicData is a string from the canvases .toDataURL() method
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileData', PicData);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('load', function () { alert('uploaded!'); });
xhr.open('POST', "/uploadSignature.aspx", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

I would like an asp page on the server end that simply receives the string, and I can then save it to disk or deal with it there. I have tried AJAX and some code for web methods but at this stage I'm just frustrating myself. Would anyone help me out with a working sample or some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code uploadSignature.aspx like any other page that processes form data.  Getting the data is pretty straightforward:

```
string value = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form['fileData'];
```

You mention saving to a file which might be more complicated than writing to a database.  I'd suggest considering writing to a database instead.  This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043332/writing-to-a-database-in-asp-net) explains a bit about writing to a database.

Comment: Thanks! That set me in the right direction! I found this sample too that seemed to make all the gaps fill in: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_asp.asp